# Best way to instantiate grid of processing elements in Verilog / SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga

I have a ProcessingElement.sv module, and I would like to instantiate a configurable array of them, so I was thinking to create a generate block like so:

```
module ProcessingArray #(parameter Y=14, X=14, W=16) (  
    input                   GlobalClk,
    input           [3:0]   OpCode,
    input           [W-1:0] DataIn,
    output logic    [W-1:0] DataOut 
    );

    

    genvar x, y;
    generate
        for (y=0; y<=Y; y++) begin 
            for (x=0; x<X; x++) begin
                ProcessingElement #(.W(16)) PE(
                    .Clk(GlobalClk),
                    .OpCode(OpCode),
                    .Input(DataIn),
                    .Output(DataOut)
                );
            end
        end
    endgenerate


endmodule
```

This seems to compile fine using Modelsim, but I'm having issues finding a smooth way to connect the array elements to one another. Generally, the connections are if x > y, the elements will be connected horizontally; if y > x, vertically; if x == y, both AND diagonally.
Here's an example of how the upper left 3x3 grid would be connected:

[Connections][1]

Is there a way to reference (eg. by naming the instances) each of the generated instances in the loops? If there were, maybe I could make another generate statement that performed all of the assigns.

I am relatively new to Verilog / SV, so if there is a better way to do this, I am happy to be enlightened

Edit:
Here is an example unrolled

```
module ProcessingArray #(parameter Y=14, X=14, W=16) (  
    input                   GlobalClk,
    input           [3:0]   OpCode,
    input           [W-1:0] DataIn,
    output logic    [W-1:0] DataOut 
    );

ProcessingElement #(.W(16)) PE_00(
    .Clk(GlobalClk),
    .OpCode(OpCode),
    .Input(DataIn),
    .Output(DataOut_00)
);

// For readability
wire wire00_01 = DataOut_00;
wire wire00_10 = DataOut_00;
wire wire00_11 = DataOut_00;

ProcessingElement #(.W(16)) PE_01(
    .Clk(GlobalClk),
    .OpCode(OpCode),
    .Input(wire00_01),
    .Output(DataOut_01)
);

wire wire01_02 = DataOut_01;

ProcessingElement #(.W(16)) PE_02(
    .Clk(GlobalClk),
    .OpCode(OpCode),
    .Input(wire01_02),
    .Output(wire02_elsewhere)
);

ProcessingElement #(.W(16)) PE_10(
    .Clk(GlobalClk),
    .OpCode(OpCode),
    .Input(wire00_10),
    .Output(DataOut_10)
);

wire wire10_20 = DataOut_10;

ProcessingElement #(.W(16)) PE_11(
    .Clk(GlobalClk),
    .OpCode(OpCode),
    .Input(wire00_11),
    .Output(DataOut_11)
);

wire wire11_12 = DataOut_11;
wire wire11_21 = DataOut_11;
wire wire11_22 = DataOut_11;

ProcessingElement #(.W(16)) PE_12(
    .Clk(GlobalClk),
    .OpCode(OpCode),
    .Input(wire11_12), 
    .Output(DataOut_12)
);

ProcessingElement #(.W(16)) PE_20(
    .Clk(GlobalClk),
    .OpCode(OpCode),
    .Input(DataIn), 
    .Output(DataOut_20)
);

ProcessingElement #(.W(16)) PE_21(
    .Clk(GlobalClk),
    .OpCode(OpCode),
    .Input(wire11_21), 
    .Output(DataOut_21)
);

ProcessingElement #(.W(16)) PE_22(
    .Clk(GlobalClk),
    .OpCode(OpCode),
    .Input(wire11_22), 
    .Output(DataOut)
);

endmodule
```

Comment: You can name loop instances by using `begin:myname`; but that won't help you. You probably need to declare arrays of internal signals that you can index into. However, your connection diagram shows PE's with different numbers of connections. You need to explain what is going on with a loop unrolled example.

Comment: If possible, I'd like to reference any of the generated ProcessingElements invidually (ie. assign .Input on any one of them any wire I choose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a 2-D array of wires, and make conditional connections inside the generate loop. Here's what a complete example looks like:

```
module ProcessingArray #(parameter Y=14, X=14, W=16) (  
    input                   GlobalClk,
    input           [3:0]   OpCode,
    input           [W-1:0] DataIn,
    output logic    [W-1:0] DataOut 
    );
  // internal connections
  wire [W-1:0] ConnIn[Y][X];
  wire [W-1:0] ConnOut[Y][X];
  // entry and exit connections
  assign ConnIn[0][0] = DataIn;
  assign DataOut = ConnOut[Y-1][X-1];

  for (genvar y=0; y<Y; y++) begin : row
    for (genvar x=0; x<X; x++) begin  :col
      ProcessingElement #(.W(16)) PE(
        .Clk(GlobalClk),
        .OpCode(OpCode),
        .Input(ConnIn[y][x]),
        .Output(ConnOut[y][x])
      );
      if (y<=x && x>0) assign ConnIn[y][x] = ConnOut[y][x-1]; // horizontal 
      if (x<=y && y>0) assign ConnIn[y][x] = ConnOut[y-1][x]; // vertical 
    end
  end

endmodule

module ProcessingElement #(int W) (
  input Clk,
  input           [3:0]   OpCode,
  input           [W-1:0] Input,
  output logic    [W-1:0] Output
);
  assign Output=Input+1;  // trace connectivity
  initial #1 $display("PE %m %d",Input);
endmodule

module tb;
  logic [15:0] in,out;
  logic [3:0] op;
  
  ProcessingArray PE(clk,op,in,out);
  
  initial begin
    in = 1;
    #1 $display(out);
  end
endmodule
```